# Put link in slider

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put link on that images on this slider: https://www.codeply.com/go/3EQkUOhhZz

I tried but the images goes smaller and got some bugs.

So i need to add a href on that images on slider

HTML

```
<div class="container text-center my-3">
<div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block col-3 img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
 display: flex;
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
transform: translateX(25%);
}
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left.active, 
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
transform: translateX(-25%);
}
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-right,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-left{ 
transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code and images here. Nobody should have to click a random link to see your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Put `d-block col-3` to anchor tag instead of `img`

```
<a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your markup like following:

```
<div class="container text-center my-3">
    <h2>Bootstrap 4 Multiple Item Carousel</h2>
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto">
        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=1"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=2"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=3"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=4"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=5"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <a href="#" class="d-block col-3"><img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/350x180?text=6"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h4>Advances one slide at a time</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: same answer already given by @Ismail Farooq. Is there anything different in your answer?

Comment: I just edited in given codeply link and pasted here this is not mandatory i don't know who give already answer or not because when I was started type answer there was no answer and was not markup in question.